# Find text of a childnode in a javatree in UFT

Tags: automation, hp-uft

I am trying to get the text/label of a child node of a javatree NOT the index.

How do i do that in UFT ?

My Java tree is as below
[image]

Code that i have tried :

```
Dim itemsCount
Dim nodeName
Dim myText
Dim selectItem()
Dim ProgramName
ProgramName = "17030-3 Parameter, programming"

itemsCount = CInt(WpfWindow("Tech Tool").JavaWindow("Program_ECU").JavaTree("Program_Control_Unit").GetROProperty("items count"))
Redim selectItem(itemsCount)
Set objItem = WpfWindow("Tech Tool").JavaWindow("Program_ECU").JavaTree("Program_Control_Unit").Object

For i = 0 To itemsCount-1
    'selectItem(i)=WpfWindow("Tech Tool").JavaWindow("Program_ECU").JavaTree("Program_Control_Unit").GetItem(i)
    selectItem(i)=WpfWindow("Tech Tool").JavaWindow("Program_ECU").JavaTree("Program_Control_Unit").Select ("#0;#"&i)

    If Trim(CStr(ProgramName)) = Trim(CStr(objItem.getItem(i))) Then
    objItem.Select(i)
    msgbox "Success"
    End If
Next
```

I have also tried using `.GetColumnValue("#0;#1")` but that also did not work

Comment: Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question in a way you describe clearly the problem, provide a sample dataset and a portion of your code. This way you show us the effort that you made on this problem and help us to address you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing JTree in UFT is complicated than it should be. Here is what I did when I had to traverse through a JTree

```
Set JTree = WpfWindow("Tech Tool").JavaWindow("Program_ECU").JavaTree("Program_Control_Unit").Object

'return how many nodes there are in the tree irrespective of their level
MsgBox JTree.getRowCount

Set JModel = JTree.getModel 'get jtree data model
Set JRoot = JModel.getRoot 'get root so that we can traverse the tree
Call JTreeWalk(JModel, JRoot)

'recursively traverse the jtree
Sub JTreeWalk(JModel, objNode)
    ctr = JModel.getChildCount(objNode)
    For i = 0 To ctr - 1
      Set objChild = JModel.getChild(objNode, i)
      If JModel.isLeaf(objChild) Then
        Print vbTab & objChild.toString
      Else
        Print "~~ " & objChild.toString & " ~~"
      End If
      Call JTreeWalk(JModel, objChild)
     Next
End Sub
```

Useful links

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html
2. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0313.html (I used this java code and converted into vbs)